# Nginx webserver not available with global IPv6 Address

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, web-server, ipv6

Recently I changed my ISP, which doesn't give out any public IPv4 addresses (CGNAT) without a monthly charge, which is the reason that I am changing the configuration of my webserver (Ubuntu 22.04 & Nginx), so it can be available with a global IPv6 address to other people with an IPv6 address. (HTTPS is yet to be configured)

However, I am now facing a problem to make my site available through IPv6.

My IP configuration:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:0f:cf:48:04:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet 192.168.1.127/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 2692sec preferred_lft 2692sec
    inet6 2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2006054652sec preferred_lft 2006054652sec
    inet6 fe80::4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

For my UFW Firewall, i opend these Ports:

```
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

My Nginx config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac]:80;

    server_name cybercluster.ch;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

Output of `nslookup cybercluster.ch`:

```
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   cybercluster.ch
Address: 2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac
```

Output of `ip -6 route`:

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a04:ee41:a:1135::/64 dev eno1 proto ra metric 100 expires 21474836sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eno1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::6e99:61ff:fe21:e4b7 dev eno1 proto ra metric 100 expires 287sec mtu 1488 pref medium
```

I have tried adding the global IPv6 address as a default route, which wasn't helpful, which is why I removed it shortly after.

When typing `curl [2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac]` or `curl localhost` i get the output of my index.html file which is located in /var/www/html.

By typing in the Link Locale IPv6 Address or the local IPv4 Address into my browser on my Windows PC, I am successfully landing on my site.

However, when typing in `cybercluster.ch` or `[2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac]` in my browser, i get the following:
[ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Fry.png)

I have tried https://ready.chair6.net/ to test my site.

The webserver can successfully ping the global IPv6 address of my Windows PC and of my router.

The webserver can successfully `ping -6 ipv6.goole.com`:

```
PING ipv6.google.com(zrh04s16-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:808::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from zrh04s16-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:808::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=2.32 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s16-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:808::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=2.20 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s16-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:808::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=2.13 ms
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.132/2.216/2.322/0.078 ms
```

To cancel out the possibillity of the problem being the firewall of my router, I tried:

- Installing XAMPP on my Windows PC and try to get on the Website with the global IPv6 Address, which was successfull.
- Trying to get on the webinterface of my router with the global IPv6 address, which was successfull.

My guess is that the webserver "doesn't want to go outside of the LAN".

The Customer Service of my ISP isn't helpful, because according to them it's "out of scope".

Does anybody have an idea? I kindly thank you in advance.

**Update 21.02.2024:**

I have captured the traffic with Wireshark while typing cybercluster.ch into my browser. In the capture I have noticed a TCP retransmission happening everytime I try to reach my Site. [image: Wireshark Capture]

What could be the cause of this TCP retransmission?

**Update 22.02.2024**

What I have changed from the initial configuration:

- Changed `listen [2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac]:80;` to `listen [::]:80;`
- Changed the remote port from 80 to any on the two Firwall Rules of my Router (the one mentioned in the comments).

Since then I have tried to acces my site but without success.

Thanks to user feedback I have read this morning, I now know that the site is available to others.
I double checked with https://ready.chair6.net/ and got a successfull pass for my site.

However i still can't access my site on my PC unless I deactivate my Windows Firewall.

What could be a possible to this?

Comment: Does your router have any kind of firewall?

Comment: @vidarlo Yes and it has five modes. Off, low, medium, high, custom.
The custom mode has per default: "LAN -> WAN: Block all Traffic" and "WAN -> LAN: Block all traffic except the incoming from traffic initiated on LAN to WAN"
I have added a rule (Local: 2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac Port 80 Remote:Any Port 80) which allows incoming connections in both ways.

Comment: Remote port will not be port 80.

Comment: @vidarlo Thank you for the hint. I have changed the remote port to ANY. However, I didn't get further.

Comment: The site responds fine for me. [This is a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/OG7Ux0X).

Comment: There is a valid AAAA DNS record?

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks for your feedback. Nice to know that the site is available.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes, there is a valid AAAA DNS record as seen above.

Answer (score 1):

A simple policy could be for a server to listen on the service port for any destination address. In nginx, unfortunately v6 is not the default if just given a port number. However can enable v6 with the unspecified address:

```
  listen      80;
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      443 ssl;
  listen      [::]:443 ssl;
```

I was able to get a http response on port 80, obviously from an address remote to you. You also should be testing public servers from an ISP that is not yours, such as from a test instance in your favorite cloud. As well as a local net that is not the same layer 2, such as a different VLAN of yours.

Start packet capture in multiple places: on the browser host, on the web server, on the switch in between. Observe if packets destined for this IP leave the user agent host, and if they arrive on the server. A firewall in between might not allow LAN to LAN or whatever zones you have.

Basic host IPv6 networking is simple and well defined. Note the router auto discovered and available via link local. You don't need to manually route `2a04:ee41:a:1135::/64`  the router already knows it, kernel route table shows it was discovered via RA.

Search for business class service. An ISP that will not assist in troubleshooting running "servers" is not helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have captured the traffic with Wireshark while typing cybercluster.ch into my browser.
In the capture I have noticed a TCP retransmission happening everytime I try to reach my Site.
`21 1.848568 2a04:ee41:a:1135:f86a:c43:2411:d00a 2a04:ee41:a:1135:4a0f:cfff:fe48:4ac TCP 86 [TCP Retransmission] 54969 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64260 Len=0 MSS=1428 WS=256 SACK_PERM`

What could be the cause of this TCP retransmission?

Comment: update the question instead of using the commantary section thank you